# Angular 6 - Is there a way to import AppModule into library?

Tags: angular6

Our application is migrated to angular 6 and looking at the ways to refactor it into smaller chunks like different modules(library).
Is there a way to refer AppModule from projects/module node module?

Answer (score 0):

If you need information from the AppModule, inject a service with that information so all the libraries can have access to it.

Look at some examples here: https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection

Comment: Thanks for your response. I think modules inside projects can not directly refer to the services from the main app. Is there an alternate like importing through AppModule?

Comment: Can you try to build an example in stackBlitz?